# How to find whether an Onvif IP camera supports NTSC vs PAL?

Tags: wsdl, streaming, ip-camera, onvif

I have an Onvif compatible IP camera which may support different codecs and resolution.

I can get information about the Streaming Profiles supported by the camera using `GetProfiles` API and get respective profile information in detail using `GetProfile` API.

But I am unable to find in what profile `NTSC/PAL` my camera would stream on certain resolution.

I have already searched through the API listed on http://www.onvif.org/onvif/ver10/media/wsdl/media.wsdl  but unable to find a filed or API which reveals the required information.

Comment: Aren't you confusing something? NTSC/PAL are analog video formats, while an IP camera outputs a digital video through the RTSP connection?

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis correct however we have othr IP camera's and we define their capabilities via a static XML which contains the NTSC/PAL format along with its other information such as resolution , fps etc.

Comment: well I still can't get the connection between ONVIF and this? You have a camera that exposes its capabilities via an XML. Ok clear. How is this related to ONVIF? You want the XML to be ONVIF compatible?

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis If a camera supports ONVIF standard it will return the XML in the ONVIF standard format. The question is that how we can get the information if a camera supports NTSC/PAL or it is not required altogether. I wanted to know this we have been configuration the NTSC/PAL as streaming profile of other IP cameras liek Cisco , Sony and Axis.